# Where do I find the polygon and vertices count for an object in Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, objects, polycount

Where do I find the polygon and vertices count for a specific object that I've selected in Blender 2.8? I'm looking for something like this:
[image]

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/status_bar.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go into edit mode, select all the vertices of the object.

You should see the counts on the bottom of the window:

[image: counts]

In some cases, the counts might not be visible by default. So if the counts aren't displaying for you, try right-clicking on the status bar and checking the box that says "Scene statistics." This should make them appear.

Comment: I don't think this is quite true anymore. It seems to always show the stats for the entire scene now, not the selected object(s). Too bad!